# .click() jquery function and Button call issue

Tags: jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

I am using image button to call a function using .click() jquery event handler

When i click on the button, it shows log ,but it doesnt show alert message. it shows alert message only when i click on the edge of the button.

Any help would be highly appreciated and need to ask why I have to put btn.

```js
$(".button").click(function(event) {
console.log('call')
if (event.target.id === "btnMakeCall") {
        var destination = "james";
        alert("destiination");
}
  });
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
  <link rel="style
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnMakeCall" class="button">
    <img src ="(http://th07.deviantart.net/fs70/150/i/2013/012/c/6/rock_01_png___by_alzstock-d5r84up.png">
</button>
```

Comment: Any javascript you wrote to use to call the function? Please put it here too.

Comment: i have added javascript function

Comment: Your code work perfect

Comment: If you want `button` without `btn` in class use `$(".button")` instead `$(".btn")`

Comment: You need to put class `.btn` class because that how that simple `jquery` code written. When an element with class `.btn` clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue. I have to add the button image as background image in css instead of using directly between the button.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .button1 {
            font-size: 18px;
            border: 2px solid #AD235E;
            background-image: url(http://th07.deviantart.net/fs70/150/i/2013/012/c/6/rock_01_png___by_alzstock-d5r84up.png);
            
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }

        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       
    </head>
            <body>
                    
                    <button id="btnMakeCall" class="button1">  </button>
                    <script src="add.js"></script>
                    
                     <script>$(".button1").click(function(event) {
                        console.log('call')
                        if (event.target.id === "btnMakeCall") {
                                var destination = "james";
                                alert("destiination");
                        }
                          });
              
              </script>
            </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set `$(".btn")` it's mean that only selector with `btn` class will select...

If you want selector **without** `btn` class and **with** `button`  class you have to set in JS    `$(".button")` instead `$(".btn")`

Learn here:https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

```js
$(".button").click(function(event) {
console.log('call')

  });
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnMakeCall" class="button">btn
    <img src="images/icon-alarm-on.png" style="width:60%; height: auto; margin: auto;" />
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much and i still have a issue . i am using a png image for that button. my issue is when i click on that image , it does shows console log output , but it does call function only when i click on the edge of the button.

Comment: If it show console it go to function  but maybe `if (event.target.id === "btnMakeCall")` is not true

Comment: i have recreated my problem through snipped as well. can u please have a look at the  code . when i click on that image it shows log , but it checks event.target only when i click on the edge of the button and display alert message